# Error importing 5 gig file into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do bulk insert into a table:

```
use SalesDWH

go


BULK INSERT dbo.npi
 FROM 'S:\tmp\npi.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='\n',lastrow=200,firstrow=2)
```

and getting this error:

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 3
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 329. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

I also tried to use sql import and export wizard to import the file. It is comma-delimited and I am getting these errors:

```
Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" (514)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" (514)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "S:\tmp\nppes\npidata_20050523-20111114.csv" on data row 79.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - npidata_20050523-20111114_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I know that my fields are definitely big enough. Here's the create statement for the table:

```
USE [SalesDWH]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[npi]    Script Date: 12/30/2011 15:28:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[npi](
    [NPI] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Entity Type Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Replacement NPI] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Employer Identification Number (EIN)] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider First Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Middle Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Name Prefix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Name Suffix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Credential Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Organization Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Organization Name Type Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Last Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other First Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Middle Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Name Prefix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Name Suffix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Credential Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Other Last Name Type Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider First Line Business Mailing Address] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Second Line Business Mailing Address] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Country Code (If outside U S )] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Telephone Number] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Fax Number] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Second Line Business Practice Location Address] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address City Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address State Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Postal Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Country Code (If outside U S )] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Enumeration Date] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Last Update Date] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [NPI Deactivation Reason Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [NPI Deactivation Date] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [NPI Reactivation Date] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider Gender Code] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Last Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official First Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Middle Name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Title or Position] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Telephone Number] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_15] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_16] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_16] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_16] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_16] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_17] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_17] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_17] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_17] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_18] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_18] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_18] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_18] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_19] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_19] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_19] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_19] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_20] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_20] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_20] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_20] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_21] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_21] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_21] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_21] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_22] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_22] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_22] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_22] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_23] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_23] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_23] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_23] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_24] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_24] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_24] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_24] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_25] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_25] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_25] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_25] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_26] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_26] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_26] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_26] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_27] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_27] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_27] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_27] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_28] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_28] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_28] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_28] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_29] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_29] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_29] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_29] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_30] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_30] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_30] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_30] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_31] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_31] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_31] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_31] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_32] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_32] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_32] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_32] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_33] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_33] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_33] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_33] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_34] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_34] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_34] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_34] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_35] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_35] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_35] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_35] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_36] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_36] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_36] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_36] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_37] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_37] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_37] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_37] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_38] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_38] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_38] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_38] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_39] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_39] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_39] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_39] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_40] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_40] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_40] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_40] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_41] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_41] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_41] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_41] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_42] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_42] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_42] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_42] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_43] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_43] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_43] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_43] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_44] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_44] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_44] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_44] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_45] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_45] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_45] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_45] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_46] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_46] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_46] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_46] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_47] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_47] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_47] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_47] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_48] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_48] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_48] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_48] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_49] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_49] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_49] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_49] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_50] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_50] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_50] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_50] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Is Sole Proprietor] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Is Organization Subpart] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Parent Organization LBN] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Parent Organization TIN] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Name Prefix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Name Suffix Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Credential Text] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_3] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_4] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_5] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_6] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_7] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_8] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_9] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_10] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_11] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_12] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_13] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_14] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_15] [varchar](80) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

I know for sure that there's no column bigger than 80 characters. I've also tried to change it to 500 characters and still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Why can I not import this file?

Here is a sample of one of the rows:
    "139236748349","1","","","","GRUrt3NERT","GEORGE","M","DR.","","M.D.","","","","","","","","","","7234900 FANNIN ST","SUITE 4423400","HOUSTON","TX","770523442900","US","713334351227000","713g25127082","792300 FANNIN ST","SUITE 423400","HOUSTON","TX","7705ef242900","US","7132225127000","713512ff27082","05/23/2005","01/22/2009","","","","M","","","","","","207VE0f2f102X","E02f945","TX","Y","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","82f4380J","04","TX","FT.BEND/MONT","B2f33159","02","TX","","8432335J","04","TX","BRAZORIA","8dd2047G","01","TX","BLUE CROSS & BLUE SHIELD","84sd2282J","04","TX","HARRIS COUNTY","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","N","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

Just an update... I changed all the fields to `nvarchar(max)`

and still getting this horrible error:

```
Operation stopped...

- Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)

- Initializing Connections (Success)

- Setting SQL Command (Success)

- Setting Source Connection (Success)

- Setting Destination Connection (Success)

- Validating (Success)
    Messages
    * Warning 0x80049304: Data Flow Task 1: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


- Prepare for Execute (Success)

- Pre-execute (Success)
    Messages
    * Information 0x402090dc: Data Flow Task 1: The processing of file "S:\tmp\nppes\npidata_20050523-20111114.csv" has started.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


- Executing (Error)
    Messages
    * Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" (514)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5" (514)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "S:\tmp\nppes\npidata_20050523-20111114.csv" on data row 79.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - npidata_20050523-20111114_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)


- Copying to [dbo].[npidata_20050523-20111114] (Stopped)

- Post-execute (Success)
    Messages
    * Information 0x402090dd: Data Flow Task 1: The processing of file "S:\tmp\nppes\npidata_20050523-20111114.csv" has ended.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Information 0x402090df: Data Flow Task 1: The final commit for the data insertion in "component "Destination - npidata_20050523-20111114" (1326)" has started.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Information 0x402090e0: Data Flow Task 1: The final commit for the data insertion  in "component "Destination - npidata_20050523-20111114" (1326)" has ended.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

    * Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "component "Destination - npidata_20050523-20111114" (1326)" wrote 58 rows.
     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data from your import file?

Comment: @JakeFeasel i wish i could but it's all private :)

Comment: Can you obfuscate the sensitive parts?

Comment: If you input only one, two, or three rows, does _that_ work? or does it only break once your file is larger than two gigabytes, four gigabytes, or ... ?

Comment: @sarnold i tried to just do a few rows. same error

Comment: @JakeFeasel i have included one row please check it out

Comment: @sarnold please take a look. ive tried to import just one row. i've included a copy of the row

Comment: I do hope it's been suitable masked / destroyed of all private value...

Comment: it sure has so do u know what the problem could be?

Comment: The sample row imports w/o any issues on my SQL Server 2008 express install

Comment: Creating the table, with either varchar(80) or nvarchar(max) gives me the warning "The table "npi" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit."  I think you may need to break apart the table structure into a couple of 1:1 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you used the Import wizard (which builds an SSIS package).

You could try to load this file using SSIS:

- Make a dataflow task
- Make a flat file source, point to csv. set parameters as you have configured.
- Set error output to redirect rows on truncation
- Add a datareader destination on the error output, attach a data viewer on the path to the data reader.
- Send the regular output to another data reader
- Run the package

You should now see if there's any rows that SSIS (import) "thinks" is more than 80 characters for some reason. You should quickly be able to identify the error(s) then.

Also, in case there are 329 columns in the csv file, check your line terminator?

Comment: @caimz thanks so much for your willingness to help. i am new to this, but didnt i use SSIS when i used the import and export wizard? if not, how do i explciitly use ssis?

Comment: Start Business Intelligence Development Studio, it is a feature you can select to install as a part of SQL Server. If you google or check youtube for "SSIS Flat file" you should find some tutorials and/or videos to get you along.

Answer (score 3):

I would validate the rows causing errors through an external script - say some quick powershell. For instance

```
$data = @(Import-Csv .\partialFile.csv )
$row = $data[0]

# how many columns do we have?
$row | gm -membertype NoteProperty | Measure-Object 

# columns larger than 80 chars
$row | gm -membertype NoteProperty | ? { ($row."$($_.Name)").Length -gt 80 }
```

Comment: Smart and quick way to check data

Comment: @scott this is not a good solution since it opens the entire file, maxing out my ram

Comment: @scott please see the edited question. ive included a sampel of the row

Answer (score 1):

Based on your table DDL, it is likely that you are hitting the max row size of 8060 in SQL. Check out the max specs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

I would, instead, try to decrease the size of the fields where possible.

Comment: This doesn't apply for variable length columns in 2008. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx

Comment: @eddie i have included a sample of the row please tell me what you think

Comment: @caimz +1 for that. ive included a copy of the row please check i out

Answer (score 1):

Create a table with the following DDL:

```
USE [YOUR_DATABASE]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[YOUR_TABLE]    Script Date: 02/21/2012 14:07:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NPI_RAW](
    [NPI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Entity Type Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Replacement NPI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Employer Identification Number (EIN)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Last Name (Legal Name)] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider First Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Middle Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Name Prefix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Name Suffix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Credential Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Organization Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Organization Name Type Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Last Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other First Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Middle Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Name Prefix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Name Suffix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Credential Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Other Last Name Type Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider First Line Business Mailing Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Second Line Business Mailing Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address City Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address State Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Postal Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Country Code (If outside U S )] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Telephone Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Mailing Address Fax Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider First Line Business Practice Location Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Second Line Business Practice Location Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address City Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address State Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Postal Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Country Code (If outside U S )] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Telephone Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Business Practice Location Address Fax Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Enumeration Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Last Update Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NPI Deactivation Reason Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NPI Deactivation Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NPI Reactivation Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider Gender Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Last Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official First Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Middle Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Title or Position] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Telephone Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Code_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Provider License Number State Code_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Primary Taxonomy Switch_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_15] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_16] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_16] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_16] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_16] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_17] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_17] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_17] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_17] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_18] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_18] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_18] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_18] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_19] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_20] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_20] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_20] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_20] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_21] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_21] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_21] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_21] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_22] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_22] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_22] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_22] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_23] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_23] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_23] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_23] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_24] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_25] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_26] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_26] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_26] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_26] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_27] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_27] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_27] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_27] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_28] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_28] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_28] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_28] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_29] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_30] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_30] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_30] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_30] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_31] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_31] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_31] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_31] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_32] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_32] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_32] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_32] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_33] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_33] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_33] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_33] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_34] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_35] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_35] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_35] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_35] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_36] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_36] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_36] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_36] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_37] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_37] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_37] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_37] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_38] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_38] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_38] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_38] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_39] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_40] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_40] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_40] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_40] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_41] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_41] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_41] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_41] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_42] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_42] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_42] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_42] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_43] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_43] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_43] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_43] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_44] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_45] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_46] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_46] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_46] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_46] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_47] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_47] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_47] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_47] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_48] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_48] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_48] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_48] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_49] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier_50] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Type Code_50] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier State_50] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Other Provider Identifier Issuer_50] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Is Sole Proprietor] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Is Organization Subpart] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Parent Organization LBN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Parent Organization TIN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Name Prefix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Name Suffix Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Authorized Official Credential Text] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_6] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_7] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_8] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_9] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_10] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_11] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_12] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_13] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_14] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Healthcare Provider Taxonomy Group_15] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Make this table the output of your dataflow in SSIS.

Good Luck!  This should work as I update my own SQL-Server (2008) destination tables based on the import of the NPPES .CSV every month.

Comment: Some of the source data columns are longer than the 50 characters. I suppose you turned off truncation errors, which results in incomplete results. The ZIP package that you download with the NPI CSV file also contains a PDF document with the record layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You may already have solved this differently, but the way it just worked me was:

1. Make a dataflow task
2. Make a flat file source, and point it to the CSV file.
3. Close the DTS package, and open the source file in the editor. It is essentially an XML file that describes the inner-workings of your package.
4. Search and replace DTS:MaximumWidth="50" with DTS:MaximumWidth="500".
5. Save the file, and re-open the DTS package. Double click on the task, and after getting a little warning about metadata inconsistency, you should be fine.
6. Create an OLE DB destination, and drag an arrow from the source to the destination. Ask it to create a new database table, which will have all the fields as varchar(500). This should be wide enough to receive all your fields into the staging table.
7. Run your package, and see how it works.

Good luck!