# When to separate tables into multiple databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am building a data warehouse. I need to get data from different sources and put it together so that I can generate reports. I will do lots of joining of tables. I am talking about maybe 20 tables total and each table is going to be anywhere from 100mb to 5 gigs.

I would like to know if I should be creating different databases for each table since each table might have an entirely different TYPE of dataset.

For example, I might have one table that has 1 GB of data about design of cars. And I will have another table with 3 GBs of sales data on these cars.

Would it be appropriate to separate these into different databases?

Please let me know what additional information is needed to advise me on this situation.

Comment: Are you planning to replicate the production data to the warehouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's a logical or business separation, by all means put them in different databases.  That's just clean data application development.  However, if you're going to be joining or merging the different data sets, then you can save some overhead and admin costs by having a single database.  20 tables total isn't a lot (I'm working on a system that has about 3700 tables, though ~1600 are audits).  Keep in mind SQL Server is meant to scale up to terabytes of data, provided you have a decent model, indexes, etc.

If you're concerned with *performance* of the warehouse, you can jam that server full of RAM and harddrives.  To leverage the harddrives properly you'd want to look at leveraging multiple files / filegroups and doling the tables out appropriately.

Comment: @ssyladin thanks! was wondering if u can help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685034/sql-server-2008-importing-5-gig-file-into-table

Answer (score 5):

Splitting into different databases would normally be in order to spread I/O load. In SQL Server you can have different filegroups within the database itself if you want to spread I/O across multiple disks groups/disks. In Warehousing scenarios you often deal with SAN solutions for Database storage, and depending on your scenario, these won't really care performance wise one way or the other, while others might give you additional performance if planned properly.

You also have table partitioning which you can look at for your growing database, but in my opinion, just make sure you have plenty of good old memory, it will benefit you more than spending time and effort in worrying about databases and files.

We are running 100gig databases in a single database file and the performance is stellar. Much of the frequently accesse data is residing in memory though, but with decent table structure and logical indexes you'll have a responsive warehouse in no time.

Comment: +1 for mention about IO bottleneck.  Separating databases makes it easy to  manage later on in this regard especially since no JOIN is required between the data sets.

Answer (score 3):

If you planning on having foreign key relationships between these tables (and it sounds like you would) then I would keep it all in one database.  Typically I use separate databases for totally separate bodies of data.

If you do separate them then you will run into some interesting challenges when you try to query both at the same time.

Comment: thanks! was wondering if u can help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685034/sql-server-2008-importing-5-gig-file-into-table